# Install smartmontools 6.2 on Ubuntu 12.04?

Tags: smart

Ubuntu 12.04 provides via apt-get smartmontools (smartctl) 5.41 (released 2011-06-09).

The latest version of smartmontools is 6.2 and the package for this is available with 14.04.

Is there any reason why I should not install the 6.2 package under 12.04?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't be able to install 6.2 version of `smartmontools` package on Ubuntu 12.04.

See [this](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/smartmontools) page.There are seperate versions of smartmontools package was developed for each Ubuntu version.

Version 6.2 was only for Ubuntu 14.04 likewise for all the other Ubuntu versions.